# Extract Reply-To in Header

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

How do I extract an email address from the internet header from outlook?

So far I have extracted the whole internet header but am stuck at regex part to get this specific string.

The reply-to in the email header is in this form

> `Reply-To: John Doe <JohnDoe123@gmail.com>`

This is what I have

```
.Pattern = "Reply-To:^<([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$>"
```

When I run the code it doesn't output anything.

Comment: Remove `$` and replace `^` with `[^<>]*`

Comment: Could you explain this more in depth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `^` matches start of the string (or line, depending on the `RegExp.Multiline` value) and the `$` matches the end of string (or line). So, the regex you have won't work.

To get the email from the `<...>` brackets after `Reply-To:` substring, you may use

```
Reply-To:[^<>]*<([^<>@\s]+@[^<>\s]+)>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gZMmvd/2)

**Details**

- `Reply-To:` - a literal string
- `[^<>]*` - 0+ chars other than `>` and `<`
- `<` - a `<` char
- `([^<>@\s]+@[^<>\s]+)` - Capturing group 1 (access this value with `match.Submatches(0)`): one or more chars other than `<`, `>`, `@` and whitespace followed with `@` and then followed with one or more chars other than `<`, `>`, and whitespace
- `>` - a `>` char.

VBA code:

```
Sub DemoFn()
   Dim re, targetString, colMatch, objMatch
   Set re = New regexp
   With re
     .pattern = "Reply-To:[^<>]*<([^<>@\s]+@[^<>\s]+)>"
     .Global = True
   End With

   targetString = "Reply-To: John Doe <JohnDoe123@gmail.com>"
   Set colMatch = re.Execute(targetString)
   If colMatch.Count > 0 Then
     Debug.Print colMatch(0).SubMatches(0)
   End If
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the run down and explaition. Greatly appreciated it

Comment: Would you be able to help me with a regex for the following format as well "John Doe sent you $213.05 (CAD)" so far I have .Pattern = "sent you\s\$\d{2,3}.\d{2}" but can't find anything

Comment: @user2057961 Why not `\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`? Please consider accepting the answer as it works for you.

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly! How about if amount are in the thousands and contain a ',' ex $1,234.00 `\$(\d+(?:\,\d+\.\d+)?)` I'm trying this regex and it will read get the full amount in the thousands but under $1,000.00 it will only spot at the decimal and won't get the cents

Comment: Edit: trying this regex and it seems to be working `\$(\d+((?:\,\d+\.\d+)|(?:\.\d+))?)` if you can think it can be simplified let me know

Comment: @user2057961 I think you may do without the pre-validation and use `\$(\d[\d,.]*)\b`